# AWS EC2 instance behind AWS ELB cannot get the real client's IP address

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services

I am very new with nginx setting. My API application running in an EC2 instance which is automatically created by my AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment.
The application ues Nginx and the instance is behind ELB load balancer (classic). Route 53 domain routes the traffic to the ELB.

I send the packet from Postman or Packet Sender to that domain, but can never receive response.
After check the nginx error log, find that the client IP is displayed as `10.0.2.63`, but not the IP address of my PC. My real IP address `149.15x.1xx.2xx`. I guess `10.0.2.63` is the VPC IP address. Below is the nginx error log.

```
while reading PROXY protocol, client: 10.0.2.63, server: 0.0.0.0:80
```

To my understanding, because the client IP is VPC IP address, the EC2 instance cannot send the reply to the real client IP address(my PC's IP address), therefore, Postmand or Packet Sender receives empty response.

Does I understand correctly? How can I let the EC2 instance receive the real client IP address? Like below:

```
while reading PROXY protocol, client: 149.15x.1xx.2xx, server: 0.0.0.0:80
```

I don't know it is the problem with AWS ELB setting or nginx setting.

The nginx config in my EC2 instance is:

```
files:
/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
content: |
  client_max_body_size 500M;
  server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

  upstream backend {
    server unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
  }

  server {
    listen 80 proxy_protocol;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;

    set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/8;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

    location / {
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $proxy_protocol_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_buffers 8 32k;
      proxy_buffer_size 64k;
      proxy_pass http://backend;
      proxy_redirect off;

      # Enables WebSocket support
      location /v1/cable {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade "websocket";
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $proxy_protocol_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_protocol_addr;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the Client IP from the [X-Forwarded-For header](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html#http-headers). This [AWS Blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-capture-client-ip-addresses/) gives you config for Apache and Nginx logs. Here's Nginx

```
http {
  ...
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
}
```

I use CloudFlare in front of my Nginx server. Here's how I replace the CloudFlare IP with the actual Client IP. You would replace "CF-Connecting-IP" with "X-Forwarded-For" and replace the IP CIDR to the CIDR of your VPC.

```
set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
```

Comment: The CIDR of my VPC is 10.0.0.0/16. I change the config to                             
set_real_ip_from 10.0.0.0/16;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;                                                                                         
But in the error log, still see the client IP address is not the real IP address. ...while reading PROXY protocol, client: 10.0.2.63, server: 0.0.0.0:80                                                                                                                                         How can I get the real IP address show in the client?

Comment: If that didn't work I'd have to play with it to work it out. They key is to get the proper IP from the headers I described above, how you do that and where it goes is for you to look into. Hopefully someone else can help, I don't do heaps with Nginx any more.